# Angular 2 Http Cache Disable

Tags: http, angular

Hello every one I need  to disable Angular 2 (Observable) http cache  for IE. But i do not have any idea how to do that. As IE 11 does not work properly while i do not open Dev Tool , I have found few suggestion and one of that is disable http cache.

Comment: Have you tried adding cache control headers to your responses?

Comment: Would you explain it a bit better . I am using Node js for back end . I would appreciate simple example . Thank you very much.

Comment: It doesnt has to do anything with your software but the HTTP-Protocoll. [Google Developers HTTP-Caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=de)

Comment: Thank you very much for answer it really solved my problem )